# How to get a row and its column from a table with Protractor

Tags: protractor

```
<div class="k-grid-content">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>row1Col1</td>
                <td>row1Col2</td>
                <td>row1Col3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>row2Col1</td>
                <td>row3Col2</td>
                <td>row4Col3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>row3Col1</td>
                <td>row3Col2</td>
                <td>row3Col3</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


var grid = element.all(by.css('.k-grid-content tr')); //this will return row1,row2,row3
```

but I am unable to use code below to get each row and its column.

```
grid.each.each(function(row){
    var rowElems = row.findElements(by.tagName('td'));
    expect(rowElems.get(0).getText()).toMatch('/Col1/');
});
```

the following error message is displaying.
 Message:
     TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'findElements'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `grid` setup is ok, but for the sake of a shortcut:

```
var grid = $$('.k-grid-content tr');
```

Regarding your question, avoid `findElements` and use chaining `element` or in this case `all` Protractor feature. But I'll use `$$` shortcut again:

```
grid.each(function(row) {
  var rowElems = row.$$('td');
  expect(rowElems.count()).toBe(3);
  expect(rowElems.get(0).getText()).toMatch('/Col1$/');
});
```

Comment: @LeoGalluci: Its kinda strange that for me ".each" did not work instead ".filter" as in 

       grid.filter(function(row) {

Any thoughts on this weird behaviour?

Comment: idk @igniteram1 notice my answer is from 2014 so it might work now