# How to get column data from a grid using protractor?

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor

I am not able to access the data in a column of grid.

Can anyone suggest method other than the one below:

```
element.all(by.repeater('col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid').column('Entity'))
    .getText()
    .then(console.log);
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML code of the repeater block? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136496/how-to-get-a-row-and-its-column-from-a-table-with-protractor

Answer (score 2):

Try using `element.all(by.css('tr')).get(rowNumber).all(by.css('td')).get(colNumber).getText();`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like :

```
 PageGrid.all(by.repeater('item in grid.items')).then(function (rows) {
                rows.forEach(function (row) {
                    row.all(by.repeater('column in row.columns')).then(function (columns) {
                        columns[3].getText().then(function (columnText) { //Fetching the desired column value from its column number in Grid which starts from 1 , not zero.
                           console.log(columnText) ;
                        });
                    });
                });
 });
```

where "PageGrid" is the unique locator for overall Grid..